# Здравствуйте, вопрос по кнопкам в Swift

Tags: swift

Суть вопроса такая, есть кнопка выполняющая действия, в которой прописано подряд много операторов if и они последовательны, и проблема в том, что после нажатия обрабатываются все if, а мне нужно остановиться на первом и ожидать следующего нажатия кнопки, что бы все происходило по очереди. 
Если какой то способ остановить действие кнопки и ждать последующего нажатия?

```
@IBAction func varib1(_ sender: Any) {

    if sceneNumber == 1 {
        sceneNumber = 2
        labelDisplayScene.text = "Вы выбили дверь несколькими ударами топора, но на вас напали разбойники, которые поджидали у двери"
        varib1Out.setTitle("Убежать", for: .normal)
        varib2Out.setTitle("Начать сражаться", for: .normal)
        varib3Out.setTitle("Попытаться договориться", for: .normal)
    }
    if sceneNumber == 2 {
        sceneNumber = 3
        labelDisplayScene.text = "Вы смогли убежать но вас ранил разбойник стрелой"
        varib1Out.setTitle("Выпить зелье", for: .normal)
        varib2Out.setTitle("Вернуться и сразиться", for: .normal)
        varib3Out.setTitle("Следовать в деревню", for: .normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя уже почти так написано, только используй `else if`.

Comment: немного не то, в дальнейшем в одной кнопке будет сотни  if(возможно это конечно неправильный подход, но пока так) и тут уже не сработает,
имеются три кнопки, каждая кнопка выбор определенного действия в зависимости от сцены (переменной)
и вот получается, что по нажатию естественно прыгает в самый последний диалог, пропуская все до него, нужно как то остановить действие кнопки в определенном месте)

Comment: разобрался с else, но код еще более глубокий в плане древа получится) хотелось бы другого решения, но все равно спасибо)